# Can't figured why header location is not working for this case (php)

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

So I'm building a website where the user registers and when logged in, he/she is able to do somethings such as unflagging quotations (adding back) that where flagged (removed from the public view) by users not registered. However, I'm having problems figuring out why my header('location: index.php') on my controller file won't redirect the page to the index.php page.I already tried to comment out all instances of echo("something") in my controller to see if that's why it's not working, but it didn't work either. I have no clues left of why  header('location: index.php') is not working.

Here is my controller file where I redirect the user after successful registration:

```
<?php 

session_start();
include "DataBaseAdaptor.php";


function GetQuotes($theDBA) {
    $array = $theDBA->getQuotesAsArray();
    $quotes = [];
    //$quotes[] = [];

    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    $id = "";
    if(count($array)>0){
    foreach($array as $item) {
        $quotes[$i][$j] = $item['quote'];
        $quotes[$i][$j+1] = $item['author'];
        $quotes[$i][$j+2] = $item['rating'];
        $quotes[$i][$j+3] = $item['id'];
        $i++; 
    }}
    return $quotes;
}
$quotes = GetQuotes($theDBA);                         //This to display the quotes initially

// This part is for registering the user
if(isset($_GET['user']) && isset($_GET['pass'])) {
    $username = $_GET['user'];
    $password = $_GET['pass'];
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);  

    // If false, then username already exists
    if (!$theDBA->register($username,  $hashed_password )) {
       //echo("Username already exists");  
    }
    else {          //The control does come to this block and the else is evaluated to true. However it won't redirect
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');

    }
}
// Register ends here----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



//This part is for adding quote
if(isset($_GET['quote']) && isset($_GET['author'])) {
    $quote = $_GET['quote'];
    $quote = str_replace("'", "", $quote);

    $author = $_GET['author'];
    $theDBA->addQuote($quote, $author);
    $quotes = GetQuotes($theDBA);
    header( 'Location: index.php' );
}


// This is for logging in
$quotes = GetQuotes($theDBA);
$user = "";
$pass = "";
if(isset($_GET['p']) && isset($_GET['q'])) {
     $user = isset($_GET['p']);
     $pass = isset($_GET['q']);

}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($quotes); $i++){
    if($user === $quotes[$i][0]) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = 'Rick';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}

echo json_encode($quotes);
?>
```

I don't know if you need my model.php (DataBaseAdaptor.php in my case), but here is. Everything related to the database, like all sql operations are working. but in case you need it, find it bellow. Feel free to send edit suggestions to my post if you find model.php not to be necessary( but please, do it only if you are sure it's not necessary). Thanks!

Here is model.php

```
<?php

//
// Author: Rick Mercer.   File name: model.php
//

class DatabaseAdaptor {
// The instance variable used in every one of the functions in class 
DatbaseAdaptor
private $DB;

// Make a connection to an existing data based named 'first' that has table 
customer
public function __construct() {
$db = 'mysql:dbname=quotes; charset=utf8; host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = ''; 

try {
  $this->DB = new PDO ( $db, $user, $password );
  $this->DB->setAttribute ( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
echo ('Error establishing Connection');
  exit ();
}
}

// Return all records as an associative array.
public function getQuotesAsArray() {
$query = "SELECT * FROM quotations WHERE flagged = 0 ORDER BY rating DESC";

$stmt = $this->DB->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute ();
// fetchall returns all records in the set as an array
return $stmt->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}

   // Checks if a user exists, if not register the new user
  public function register($username, $password) {
  $query = "SELECT * from users";
  $stmt = $this->DB->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute ();

// fetchall returns all records in the set as an array
$array = $stmt->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

// If there are no registered users, just register the new user
if(count($array) == 0) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES ('$username', 
'$password')";
    $stmt = $this->DB->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute ();
    return true;
 // header( 'Location: index.php' );
}

foreach($array as $item) {
    if($username == $item['username']) {
        return false;
    }
}
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES ('$username', '$password')";
    $stmt = $this->DB->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute ();
    return true;
   //header( 'Location: index.php' );
 }


 public function addQuote($quote, $author) {
 $query = "INSERT INTO quotations (added, quote, author, rating, flagged) 
 VALUES(now(), '$quote', '$author', 0, 0)";
 $stmt = $this->DB->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute ();
 }


 } // End class DatabaseAdaptor

$theDBA = new DatabaseAdaptor();
?>




Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
```

Comment: 1st: add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096) to start of you page and see what that gives you. 2nd: **always** do `exit` after header, since it does not stop the script. 3rd: are you sure your script even gets to the header part? Maybe the `if` above always goes into first option

Comment: I updated the post to add the model.php where the function in the if statement gets its value. That function returns true or false, and I know the script gets to the header part because when the user is successfully registered, that function returns true. And I'm able to register users, so the function returns true, which makes the else statement be evaluated to true. Also, I at first I thought the same, and tried to add the header part in the other if branch just to check, and nothing happened. So the if statement is definitely not the problem.

Comment: use ob_start() at start of script()

Comment: just added exit() after header, and also just used ob_start() at the start of the script, first before session_start() and it didn't work. Tried after session_start(), it didn't work either

Comment: if (!$theDBA->register($username,  $hashed_password )) { //try remove ! infront of $theDBA. You checking if the user already exists but your code tells, if user not exists...

Comment: The reason why I have if (!$theDBA->register($username, $hashed_password ))  is because when that is true, username exists since that function returns false when username already exists, and I don't want to redirect on that condition being true

Comment: your code seems ok. may b you try with chrome incognito or private window. may be cache problem...

Comment: I tried to comment out the isset conditions and hard code values for user and password, and when I ran controller, it  redirected to index.php, which I don't understand why it worked in this cases. But when I do not comment out  isset and use the values of user and password that I get from the registration form, the problem remains and it won't redirect.  Any ideas why is that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `header();` with `echo 'redirecting...';` and see if your code reaches header part or no.
2. If you could see "redirecting..." then something prevents `header` from running. For example, there might be a warning or something  that comes before `header`. In that case, try to solve that warning or (not a good idea) try `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean` to prevent flushing anything to output.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem in the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && isset($_GET['q'])) {
     $user = isset($_GET['p']);
     $pass = isset($_GET['q']);

}
```

$user and $pass will always get the value 0 or 1 and therefore the next part of your code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($quotes); $i++){
    if($user === $quotes[$i][0]) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = 'Rick';
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

will be unlikely to evaluate to true (unless the $quotes array has the values 0 or 1) and the header redirection will not fire.

Looks to me like the user and password should be set as follows:

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && isset($_GET['q'])) {
     $user =$_GET['p'];
     $pass = $_GET['q'];
}
```

Hopefully this is the problem.

Comment: I just did that and the problem remains. I mean even if that was a problem, the code above it, has header too but it's never redirected either. But yeah, I edited my code based on what you suggested. Thanks for that part btw, it's a mistake I didn't notice. However, the problem posted still remains. Header still won't redirect

Comment: Not sure if you tried this, but if you put header('Location: index.php'); outside of all your conditionals, i.e. just before echo json_encode($quotes); as a test does it redirect?

Comment: yes it does becaus when I did that json_encode($quotes);  is not evaluated. I can see that because the page keeps redirecting to index.php when I run controller.php. Also, I tried to comment out the isset conditions and hard code values for user and password, and when I ran controller, it also redirected to index.php, which I don't understand why it worked in those two cases. Any ideas why is that?